# Iterate over `True` entries of Boolean Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, iterable

I want a loop for each index `i` at which array `X` (which is **Boolean**) is `True`.

Is there something more efficient/pythonic than wrapping `np.nonzero` inside `np.nditer` as follows?

```
for i in np.nditer(np.nonzero(X), flags=['zerosize_ok']):
    myfunction(Y[i],Z2[Z[i]])
```

The problem here is that it iterates twice instead of just once, and occupies memory (first, `np.nonzero` iterates through `X` and stores that to a big array, then `np.nditer` iterates through that array).

Is there a command (slightly similar to `np.nditer`, so to speak) for efficiently iterating over `True` entries of a Boolean array directly, without listing them all explicitly with `np.nonzero` first? (Iterating over all entries and checking each with an `if` statement is probably less efficient than some iterator offered by Numpy, if it exists.)

Comment: What makes your code slow is mostly the CPython function call and the many direct access to the Numpy array in the loop. Removing the second one can increase a bit the performance but then the function call will still be a huge bottleneck. There is no way to remove the function call without changing the function itself (either using trivial decorators or by rewriting the function totally). Can you describe/share what this function does?

Comment: @JérômeRichard If the function becomes too complicated, then removing the function call might be out of the question, right? I'm asking whether `np.nditer(np.nonzero(X), flags=['zerosize_ok'])` can be replaced by something more efficient/pythonic; in its current form, it iterates twice instead of just once, and occupies memory (first `np.nonzero` iterates through `X` and stores that to a big array, then `np.nditer` iterates through that array).

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your input and the custom function but it is very unlikely that slowness comes from doing the iteration twice. `np.nonzero` is pretty fast even for very large arrays.

Comment: @root The double iteration is clearly not a problem here. The `np.nonzero(X)` call is very fast compared to the iteration (~17 time faster) and the function call (~25 time). This is because Numpy do native calls and the CPython interpreter is insanely slow. If you want a fast code you need to remove every use pure-Python code in hot paths. Iterables are slow too due to the way they are designed in Python (and the interpreter). As for the function, there are things like `np.vectorize` in Numpy but they are not efficient (due to the previous mentions: Numpy cannot overpass CPython rules).

Comment: @root Once vectorization is left apart because the function is assumed not to be vectorizable (manually). The only remaining option is to bypass CPython for example by using a embedded JIT/AOT compiler or not using CPython (see PyPy which is a JIT). However, this embedded compiler tools require the function to be decorated and/or restricted to some operations. As for PyPy (or other interpreters) they have few restrictions too and using another interpreter if often not free. I think there are no other solution.

Answer (score -1):

People downvote because looping over the entries of a numpy array is a big nono. We are using numpy because it's fast and treating every element by itself rather than operating on the whole array at once makes it so you're getting python level performance rather than numpy/c performance.

Wanting to exclude values by giving an array with true and false values is very common and is called masking. you can do it by indexing into the true false array. To do that in numpy you use indexing. E.g. you do  `np.array([1,2,3])[np.array([True,False,True])]`. And it gives you `np.array([1, 3])`.

So basically try arranging things in a way that you can do

```
myfunction(Y[mask],Z2[Z[maks]]).
```

There are a couple of techniques of doing that. One way is only using numpy functions to create myfunction and an other one is to use decorators like `numba.vectorize`, `numba.guvectorize` or `numba.njit` and a few more.

Comment: Your answer is based on the assumption that `myfunction` can be vectorized; my question is about the general case where it cannot. I'm looking for an iterator that goes through indices of `True` values of `X` directly and efficiently, if such an iterator exists.

Comment: @root Well every function can be vectorized. It's just a question of if you want to invest the time and energy. My point is that you don't get good performance out of numpy if you don't vectorize. And sometimes that's fine. But don't talk about efficiency then.

Comment: @root But I believe what you're looking for might be np.where(mask)[0]. It gives you the indices were mask is true.

Comment: Some functions (in the Python sense of the word "function") modify global variables (or their inputs, if they are mutable) (or their output is used for their future inputs), so the flow or result of the second call can depend on the result of the first call. They can't be vectorized, right?

Comment: What's the advantage of `np.where(X)[0]` over what I'm using, namely `np.nonzero(X)`?

Comment: @root You're way of thinking about vectorisation is valid but not relevant for efficiency. In the sense that matters for efficiency, the numpy sense, vectorisation means getting a low level compiled function that works on the whole array and is fast. That is the idea of numpy. And that's definitely possible for all functions only receiving and returning numpy arrays.

Comment: @root I believe mostly a way more descriptive name. but also you can give it the arrays and directly get the elements.

Answer (score -1):

How about using [**numpy.vectorise**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) with an boolean selector as an index?

np.vectorise takes a function and returns a vectorised version of that function that accepts arrays.  You can then run the function on the array or a subset of it using a selector.

In numpy you can subselect using an [index of an array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) using a list of numbers.

The [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function returns the indexes of an array that match some value or function.

Putting that together:

```
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(0) # For repeatability

def myfunction(y, z, z2):
    return y*z2[z]

Y = np.array(range(100))  # Array of any length
Z = np.array(range(len(Y)))  # Must be the same length as Y
Z2 = np.array(range(len(Y))) # Must be constrained to indexes of X, Y and Z
X = [random.choice([True, False]) for toss in range(len(Y))] # Throw some coins

# X is now an array of True/False
# print( "\n".join(f"{n}: {v}" for n, v in enumerate(X)))
print(np.where(X)) # Where gets the indexes of True items

# Vectorise our function
vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunction, excluded={2}) # We exclude {2} as it's the Z2 array

# Do the work
res = vfunc(Y[np.where(X)],Z[np.where(X)],Z2)

# Check our work
for outpos, inpos in enumerate(np.where(X)[0]):
    assert myfunction(Y[inpos], Z[inpos], Z2) == res[outpos], f"Mismatch at in={inpos}, out={outpos}"

# Print the results
print(res)
```

Comment: Your answer is based on the assumption that `myfunction` can be vectorized; my question is about the general case where it cannot. I'm looking for an iterator that goes through indices of `True` values of `X` directly and efficiently, if such an iterator exists.

Comment: Are you saying that your example is not a true use case in your application.  My example shows that you can use your example without a Python iterator, which is slow compared to pure numpy.  Please provide a more accurate use case.

Comment: My question is whether there's some `bool_iter` function (for iterating over the indices of `True` entries of a Boolean array) such that `for i in np.nditer(np.nonzero(X), flags=['zerosize_ok'])` (two iterations: one by `np.nonzero` and one by `np.nditer`) can be replaced by something like `for i in bool_iter(X)` (one iteration). In your solution, there are still several iterations (indexing into `Y` and `Z`, then iterating through the result). (And there's additional memory usage due to arrays like `Y[np.where(X)]`, which may or may not be good for the memory/runtime trade-off).